# How do i parse json data retrieved from php script in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Please somebody help me, am new to ajax, i have been trying to read json data from php script but just no success.
when i console.log the data i get this,

```
{"name":"JOHN","surname":"FIGO","sex":"M","Records_id":"1","student":""}.
```

and when i do this `console.log(data[2]);` i simply get `n` character. what i want is to get the values, for example, `console.log(data['name']);` should give `JOHN`or `console.log(data[0]);` should give `JOHN`. when i use either javascript or jquery parse methods, i get an error, i dont understand. Here is are the codes;

```
<?php 
$conn= new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'Goldfinger');

$query= 'SELECT * FROM records';

$result= $conn->query($query);

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo json_encode($row);

}
?>
```

and jquery;

```
$('#one').click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxtesting.php',
            type: 'POST',       
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data['name']);
                };
            }, 
            error: function () {
                $('div:not(#one)').text('error dude!');
            }
        })
    })
```

pardon my code if it's very poor. Thank you in advance.

Comment: use 
`console.log(data.name)
console.log(data.surname)`

Comment: am getting undefined!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `dataType : 'json',` inside ajax setting like so :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxtesting.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType : 'json', //<------------- here   
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log(data['name']);
            };
        }, 
        error: function () {
            $('div:not(#one)').text('error dude!');
        }
    })
```

or simply parse inside success callback :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxtesting.php',
        type: 'POST',       
        success: function (data) {
           var myData = $.parseJSON( data ); //<------- here
            if ( myData ) {
                console.log(myData['name']);
            };
        }, 
        error: function () {
            $('div:not(#one)').text('error dude!');
        }
    })
```

Comment: by default i think ajax returns a JSON if you dont specify it.Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Comment: If no dataType was specified, jQuery will try to refer based on the MIME type of the response, otherwise string will returned. It common practice to specify the dataType other than string.

Comment: I see i thought the default is `JSON` if you dont specify anything thank you for clarification. I hope you explain this in the answer and also provide a documentation for better understating of the OP as well

Comment: for your first method i get the error, while the second gives, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {,   ajax.html1.

Comment: I guess something wrong with `echo json_encode($row);`, why you put inside loop anyway?

Comment: Mr Ghazali you are the best! it was the loop indeed. Am so happy. thank you so much